# Define dynamic entity property/function

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an Entity called `Task`. A task can have child tasks. In my dal I am trying to automatically evaluate the child count every time I fetch a task from my entity model. The child count is not stored in the database.

For example, let's look at my Fetch method:

```
public TaskDto Fetch(Guid id)
{
    using (var ctx = ObjectContextManager<MyDataContext>.GetManager("MyDataContext"))
    {
        var data = (from t in ctx.ObjectContext.Tasks
                    join tty in ctx.ObjectContext.TaskTypes on t.Id equals tty.Id
                    where t.EntityGuid == id
                    select new
                    {
                        Task = t,
                        ChildCount = TaskChildCount(t.EntityGuid)
                    }).FirstOrDefault();

        if (data == null)
        {
            throw new RecordNotFoundException("Task");
        }

        return ReadData(data.Task, data.ChildCount);
    }
}
```

But instead of calling ReadData with the 2 params, I just want to call it with a Task param: `ReadData(data.Task)` and the ChildCount to automatically be there. Is there some way I can bake this into my Task entity? It is a very simple function:

```
public int TaskChildCount(Guid currentTaskId)
{
    var ret = 0;

    using (var ctx = ObjectContextManager<MyDataContext>.GetManager("MyDataContext"))
    {
        ret = ctx.ObjectContext.Tasks.Count(x => x.ParentId != currentTaskId);
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: i dont follow.   what is ReadData?   And you want to put DAL calls in your model ? SHouldnt you inject a IRepository object?

Comment: ReadData takes the parameter (a Task entity) and returns a TaskDto - a data contract object. I am not putting dal calls in my model. The code above is in TaskDal which is called through a repository from my business layer, but that's irrelevant.

Comment: If you have a navigation property from your task to your task children you should be able to query from the passed task object.

Comment: This may be of interest: http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/24/client-side-properties-and-any-remote-linq-provider

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this, but `Task` will always need some help. You could `Include` the child records of `Task`:

```
from t in ctx.ObjectContext.Tasks.Include(t => t.Tasks)
```

Now `Task` can have a property `TaskCount` that returns `this.Tasks.Count`.

You'd have to access this property outside the scope of a LINQ query, otherwise EF will try to translate it into SQL and fail.

The downside is that it populates all `Task`s contained by a parent `Task`, which is a lot heavier than just getting a count from the database. Therefore a better way could be to use [`AutoMapper`s](http://automapper.org/) capability to project nested properties by name convention. Suppose your `TaskDto` would have a property `TasksCount`, then you could do:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Task, TaskDto>();
var data = ctx.ObjectContext.Tasks.Project().To<TaskDto>();
```

(`Project` is an extension method in `AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions`, AutoMapper can be obtained through Nuget).

I leave out the `join` and `where` for simplicity, but these would not change the concept. AutoMapper does not find `TasksCount` in `Task` itself, so by convention it tries to find a property `Tasks` to which it can apply `Count()`. It finds the child collection `Tasks` (well, maybe you named it differently) and there you go. You will see that the count is neatly integrated in the SQL query that is generated.

The difference is that the dto is created by the `Fetch` method itself, not by `ReadData`. I can't judge whether this causes any problems. Maybe you have to shuffle some code in order to use this AutoMapper feature.